# Conflict between apache 2.4.1 and 2.2.2? Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, osx-lion

I recently installed Apache 2.4.1 on my mac(10.7) and executed "httpd". I received these two error messages when **websharing was turned off** in system preferences:

```
//(1)-In the console//
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using         192.168.1.65 for ServerName
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

//(2)-In the browser//
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 0.0.0.0 Port 80
```

// 2nd Test for Clarification

Quick experiment: **Websharing turned on**.

- I switched to the 2.4.1 folder and ran "apachectl start". Here is the code:

  ```
  usr/local/apache2/bin] root# apachectl start
  org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
  ```
- I checked 0.0.0.0 on chrome
- The message, "It works", popped up. No sign of the apache 2.2.2 404 error message seen when websharing was off.
- I typed in terminal "apachectl stop"
- I checked 0.0.0.0 again and received the message "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 0.0.0.0."

//Added clarification 3/25/12

This mac already came pre-installed with apache 2.2.2. Does the presence of it (It is not running. I had the websharing option turned off.) on my hard drive interfere with the recent installation of apache 2.4.1?

When I turn websharing on, I do not get the apache 2.2.2 404 error message but the index.html page at 0.0.0.0:80. I don't understand why apache 2.4.1 will not run even when the websharing option is turned off. ***I think when I execute "apachectl start" in "usr/local/apache2/bin/" the computer activates apache 2.2.2 instead of 2.4.1.*** Why?

Could anyone add some clarity to this problem? I want to use apache 2.4.1 instead of being forced to use apache 2.2.2. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can't bind two different programs to the same IP/port. If 2.2 is already running on port 80, then you can't also run 2.4 on the same port. You can, however, run both at the same time if they're both using different ports, e.g. 2.2/80 and 2.4/8080

Comment: Does that error message occur because apache 2.2 is running? I could be wrong but I thought it was turned off unless the web sharing option was turned on. Do I need web sharing activated to run apache?